# No connection string named "NorthwindConnection" could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 projects: Console app and dll. In dll i am using EntityFramework. I have this app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="NorthwindConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ВЛАДИСЛАВ-ПК\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=sa;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

I am calling EntityFramework from console app, but i have this error message: "No connection string named "NorthwindConnection" could be found in the application config file.".

This is console app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Found the solution! I added EF references both to console app and to dll, deleted app.config from dll and added app.config to console app and write there data from first code block wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Copy following tag from your .dll config file into your console project `app.config`:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ВЛАДИСЛАВ-ПК\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=sa;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So your `app.config` in your console project will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ВЛАДИСЛАВ-ПК\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=sa;"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```